# Is there a way to perform a circular bit shift in C#?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I know that the following is true

```
int i = 17; //binary 10001
int j = i << 1; //decimal 34, binary 100010
```

But, if you shift too far, the bits fall off the end.  Where this happens is a matter of the size of integer you are working with.

Is there a way to perform a shift so that the bits rotate around to the other side?  I'm looking for a single operation, not a for loop.

Comment: Where would an operation of this type be used? What is the purpose behind doing a Bit Rotate? I don't need to know, but am just interested in ever expanding knowledge.

Keith

Comment: a very good question. I just checked the generated code and the C# compiler doesn't generate code that uses the rotate instructions of the CPU (not that the x86 architecture has them since the 8086...). This is a shame. C does this optimization. Also rotations are very important for crypto and dsp tasks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you know the size of type, you could do something like:

```
uint i = 17;
uint j = i << 1 | i >> 31;
```

... which would perform a circular shift of a 32 bit value.

As a generalization to circular shift left n bits, on a b bit variable:

```
/*some unsigned numeric type*/ input = 17;
var result = input  << n | input  >> (b - n);
```

---

@The comment, it appears that C# does treat the high bit of signed values differently.  I found some info on this [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpShiftOperators.aspx).  I also changed the example to use a uint.

Comment: Since I don't know C#, are the shift operators doing arithmetic or logic shifts? If arithmetic, then this algorithm can't be used for 64-bit signed integers.

Comment: So perhaps both the 'int' and 'var' types should be prefixed with an 'unsigned' modifier, of course if C# allows that.

Comment: Well, rotation of bits only makes sense with unsigned integers anyway.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I wouldn't necessarily agree with that. [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) returns a (signed) `int`, and if you want to evenly distribute hash codes by using the full 32 bits of that (which *can* involve bit rotation), the sign doesn't really matter - and apparently gets in the way of bit rotation.

Comment: If you use `i << n | i >> -n` (or alternatively, `i << n | i >> ~n >> 1`) then you don't have to change the value of `b` for different sizes. It could theoretically be marginally faster too, but not so that you'd ever notice.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper true, but really `GetHashCode` should be considered a `uint` but it has to be an `int` to be CLS compliant. If you're going to bit-fiddle with it, it really only makes sense to either cast to `uint` or mask out the sign bit. Most uses of the result will need you to mask out the sign bit anyway (e.g. indexing from a modulus).

Comment: Also of note, the second example will never work on its own -- you use the undeclared variable "i" instead of the intended "input".  (And if you switch it to input, the compiler will still turn that into a regular int, not a uint).

Comment: Strange that it would even need this much code, given the fact both `ror` and `rol` are part of the bare x86 CPU instruction set. Couldn't they just have made a `<<>` instruction or something for that in C#?

Answer (score 12):

One year ago I've to implement MD4 for my undergraduate thesis. Here it is my implementation of circular bit shift using a UInt32.

```
private UInt32 RotateLeft(UInt32 x, Byte n)
{
      return UInt32((x << n) | (x >> (32 - n)));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Sincce .NET Core 3.0 and up there's [`BitOperations.RotateLeft()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.rotateleft?view=netcore-3.1) and [`BitOperations.RotateRight()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.rotateright?view=netcore-3.1) so you can just use something like

```
BitOperations.RotateRight(12, 3);
BitOperations.RotateLeft(34L, 5);
```

In previous versions you can use [`BitRotator.RotateLeft()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.utilities.bitrotator.rotateleft?view=visualstudiosdk-2015) and [`BitRotator.RotateRight()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.utilities.bitrotator.rotateright?view=visualstudiosdk-2015) in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities

Answer (score 4):

Just as reference on how to do it, these two functions work perfectly for rotating the bits of 1/2word:

```
static public uint ShiftRight(uint z_value, int z_shift)
{
    return ((z_value >> z_shift) | (z_value << (16 - z_shift))) & 0x0000FFFF;
}

static public uint ShiftLeft(uint z_value, int z_shift)
{
    return ((z_value << z_shift) | (z_value >> (16 - z_shift))) & 0x0000FFFF;
}
```

It would be easy to extend it for any given size.

Answer (score 1):

The extension methods for rotating bits of a `uint` (32 bits):

```
public static uint ROR(this uint x, int nbitsShift)
    => (x >> nbitsShift) | (x << (32 - nbitsShift));

public static uint ROL(this uint x, int nbitsShift)
    => (x << nbitsShift) | (x >> (32 - nbitsShift));
```