# Efficiently shift an integer to the left and wrap around

Tags: c#, optimization, bit-manipulation

How can I efficiently shift every bit in an integral type to the left, and wrap around so that the leftMost bit becomes the rightmost?

eg if the type was a byte, then:

```
1111,1110 becomes 1111,1101
0000,0001 becomes 0000,0010
1000,0000 becomes 0000,0001
```

At the moment I'm using this:

```
//num is an ulong
bool leftMostSet = (num & 0x8000000000000000) == 0x8000000000000000;
num = num << 1;
num = num | (leftMostSet ? (ulong)1 : 0);
return num;
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient method though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812022/c-sharp-bitwise-rotate-left-and-rotate-right

Comment: The dupe is for C, not C# but it looks like it'll work anyway. If not, come back and [edit] this so it can be reopened.

Comment: Thanks, those answers work, although I don't know if the compiler optimizations will

Comment: The jitter knows this pattern and will use rotate machine code.

Comment: Thanks @JonHanna. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @YairHalberstadt I'm afraid not. I do recall it being noted as such by people in the know among the corefx developers.