# C#: How to Rotate Left the Bits of a Byte?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a byte array containing `0xE1` and `0x04` and I need to manipulate it into producing `0x104` and I'm struggling with it. I've been told to do the following:

> 1. 0xE1 AND 0x1F = 0x01
> 2. Rotate left 8 bits = 0x100
> 3. 0x04 ADD 0x100 = 0x104

The raw instructions from the manufacturer:

> - *0xE1 is greater than 0xE0*
> - *0xE1 AND 0x1F = 0x01*
> - *Rotate left 8 bits = 0x100*
> - *Read next byte = 0x04*
> - *0x04 Add 0x100 = 0x104*

I can't get #2 to work. I've tried the extension methods from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812022/c-sharp-bitwise-rotate-left-and-rotate-right), the [BitRotator.RotateLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.utilities.bitrotator.rotateleft?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) method, and the [BitOperations.RotateLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.rotateleft?view=netcore-3.1) method, all without successfully getting `0x100`. What am I supposed to do to get to `0x100`?

I've never had to do bit-level operations before, so I'm struggling with it.

**Update**

I'm parsing a GPS report. There's fields in the report that are 1 or 2 bytes in size. If the value of byte `0` is less than `0xE0` then the size of the field is 1 byte. Else, the size is 2 bytes and I'm supposed to use the steps above to get to the real value. To quote the docs:

> *Any fields designated as 1-byte/2-byte fields are unsigned integers using the following encoding:
> If the 1st byte is less then 0xE0 (decimal 224) then the field size is 1-byte and the value is the value of the entire byte. If the 1st byte is greater-or-equal to 0xE0 then the field size is 2-bytes and the value is the value of the lsb 13-bits of the 2-byte field (most-significant byte first).*

Here's the method I'm using (prototyping in LINQPad):

```
private static OneTwoField<Type> GetItemType(
    ReadOnlySpan<byte> itemBytes) {
    if (itemBytes[0] < 224) {
        return new OneTwoField<Type>(1, (Type)itemBytes[0]);
    }

    itemBytes[0..2].DumpToTable();

    //  What do I do to get to the real value?
    var type = ???;

    return new OneTwoField<Type>(2, type);
}
```

The `DumpToTable()` extension produces the following:

[image: DumpToTable() results]

Here's the `OneTwoField<T>`:

```
public struct OneTwoField<T> {
    public OneTwoField(
        byte size,
        T value) {
        Offset = size == 1 ? 0 : 1;
        Size = size;
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Offset { get; }
    public byte Size { get; }
    public T Value { get; }
}
```

And here's the `Type`:

```
[Flags]
public enum Type :
    short {
    General = 0x00,
    Versions = 0x104
}
```

Comment: The result of `0x100` does not fit in a `byte` so what is the actual type you're using?  A left rotate of 8 bits on a byte should just result in the exact same value.  Please show the exact code you tried so we can help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @juharr, I've updated the question with more information about what I'm dealing with and how I'm dealing with it.

Comment: That quote says _lsb 13-bits of the 2-byte field_.  I assume that should be "last" and not "lsb"?

Comment: Also `Type` is a horrible name to use for your enum since that's already the name of a class. And that is clearly not a set of flags (those would have powers of 2 increasing from 0 up).  It seems like you really just need constant values instead and `OneTwoField` doesn't need to be generic

Comment: That's what the docs say, so I can't really answer the question. All I have to go off of is the docs (which have proven wrong in other areas) and the instructions provided by the manufacturer on how to read if its 2 bytes (I've quoted them as well now). Naming is all up in the air right now. I've had to change it a dozen times as I scrape by. It should probably be `ItemType`, but like I said, this is a prototype.

Comment: When the first byte is < 0xE0 then the value is just the second byte, otherwise I think you want `((bytes[0] & 0x1F) << 8) | bytes[1]`  but your issue seems to be with trying to turn that value into an enum.  Just save it as a `short` or `int` or whatever type will hold the 2 byte value.

Comment: YES! That worked! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. You're right about the `[Flags]` on `Type`, I've removed the attribute. I made `OneTwoField` generic because it's used in other parts of the report. So far its either a `short` or the `Type` enum which I've constrained to a short, so I guess I could un-genericize it? Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

[Bitwise left shift operator `<<`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#left-shift-operator-)

```
byte step1 = 0xE1 & 0x1F; //0x01
short step2 = step1 << 8; //0x100
```