# Bit Right Rotate Through Carry implementation "C#"

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I know there is similar questions to my question, however, they aren't the same. All of them are just normal shifts, circular shifts etc. not having a through Carry flag.

I am trying to implement a method that does a right rotate through carry flag, carry flag being 1, current code:

```cs
public static int RotateRight(int value, int count = 2)
{
   uint val = (uint)value;
   return (int)((val >> count) | (val << (32 - count)));
}
```

However, this works only as normal shift, an input of 16 returns 4. How would one create a carry flag?

Before an admin points to this question [C# bitwise rotate left and rotate right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812022/c-sharp-bitwise-rotate-left-and-rotate-right) this does a normal rotate without a through carry flag.

[Rotate through carry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuHnN.png)

Another example of this:

```
10 >> 2 with carry through flag of 1

1   00010000    
Rotate with carry   >>  2   
0   10001000    
0   01000100
```

Comment: `carry flag being 1` - what do you mean by this? - going in, coming out? Where is this value being held in your code sample?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError well that is the issue, I am not sure how to reimplement this flag with a bitwise operation. As x >> 2 does the bitshift in code I am note sure I can modify it to add the 1 at the start. I tried using a hacky method. Convert decimal to string with already shifted values, add 1 at index 1  ( shifted by 2), however this is kind of a hacky way of doing it and doesn't cover all cases

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, here my really straigth-forward, off the top of my head, totally unoptimized way of doing it:

```
int RotateRightThroughCarry(uint value, int count, ref uint carry)
{
  // width assumed to be 32 bits
  // carry assumed to be either 0 or 1    
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    value = RotateRightOneBitThroughCarry(value, ref carry);
  return value;
}

int RotateRightOneBitThroughCarry(uint value, ref uint carry)
{
  int newCarry = value & 1;
  int newValue = (value >> 1) | (carry << 31);
  carry = newCarry;
  return newValue;
}
```

Comment: Is `count` represents the shift? In addition, shouldn't RotateRightThroughCarry(first method) return a result or save it to a variable and return the final result?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Fixed that in my edit already, I believe.