# Rotate digits of an integer

Tags: c#, math, integer, rotation, digits

I am attempting to come up with a generic function that will rotate the digits of a given number to the left or the right by `n`. At this point I've only been able to work out an implementation for left shift:

```
public static T RotateDigitsLeft<T>(this T value, int count) where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
    var absoluteValue = T.Abs(value: value);
    var countAsT = T.CreateTruncating(value: count);
    var digitCount = absoluteValue.LogarithmBase10();
    var factor = BinaryIntegerConstants<T>.Ten.Exponentiate(exponent: (digitCount - countAsT));
    var endDigits = (absoluteValue / factor);
    var startDigits = (absoluteValue - (endDigits * factor));

    return T.CopySign(sign: value, value: ((startDigits * BinaryIntegerConstants<T>.Ten.Exponentiate(exponent: countAsT)) + endDigits));
}
```

- Is it possible to alter this in a way that works for negative values of `count`?
- A subset of rotations result in invalid values, depending on the size of `T`; is there a decent way to check for these generically so that one can throw?
- Can one alter the function to support right rotation as well?

**Note:** Answers that continue to use arithmetic will be preferred because I find them more interesting.

**Examples:**

- `54321` -> `43215` (rotate left by 1, rotate right by 4)
- `54321` -> `32154` (rotate left by 2, rotate right by 3)
- `54321` -> `21543` (rotate left by 3, rotate right by 2)
- `54321` -> `15432` (rotate right by 1, rotate left by 4)
- `54321` -> `21543` (rotate right by 2, rotate left by 3)
- `54321` -> `32154` (rotate right by 3, rotate left by 2)
- `1123456789` -> `1234567891` (rotate left by 1)
- `1123456789` -> `EXCEPTION` (rotate right by 1)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812022/c-sharp-bitwise-rotate-left-and-rotate-right) related post?

Comment: @AxelKemper Sorry, that's about rotating *bits*; our goal is to rotate *digits*.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 bits are effectively just base 2 digits. The logic is the same, except bits let you leverage hardware bitops.

Comment: @Luatic Great, now draw the rest of the owl.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 on it right now, but first had to install mono since I normally don't do C# :)

Comment: That's the spirit! May I suggest [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net)? Saves one from defiling their own machine.

Comment: There's LinqPad as well, no need to defile anything.

Comment: @Luatic There seems to be another difference here: OP wants to rotate based on how many digits are actually in the value, not just on how many it could fit.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 added my answer; it's pretty simple in principle, but I'm having trouble fighting C#; where does `LogarithmBase10` come from? Could you provide more context (ideally a working fiddle)? :)

Comment: @Luatic That's my fault as it's not built-in; see [here](https://github.com/ByteTerrace/Ouroboros.Maths/blob/main/Project/BinaryIntegerFunctions.cs) for missing classes/functions.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a right rotation of n digits is equivalent to doing a left rotation of m - n digits for a number of m digits:

As an example, to rotate 123456 right by two, we rotate left by 6 - 2 = 4:

123456 → 612345 → 561234 → 456123 → 345612

This is equivalent to rotating right twice:

123456 → 234561 → 345612

Thus we only need to make a simple change to support negative rotation values:

```cs
if (count < 0) countAsT += digitCount;
```

right after the `digitCount` has been computed, and before doing the rest of the rotation. I'm not sure whether this is correct type-wise though; I can't find documentation for the return type of `LogarithmBase10`. It would be sensible for it to be an `int` though; if it isn't, you'd have to cast it.

I've created a minimal [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SGfhT1) based on Dmitry's fiddle for you to test this.

Comment: If it's easier, feel free to write `T` as `int` or `uint`; one can perform the mechanical translation to generic interfaces from there.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 it's working now. I simply had to use `countAsT` since `digitCount` is a `T`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest converting integer to `string` rotate it and then `Parse` back to integer:

```
public static T RotateDigitsLeft<T>(this T value, int count) 
  where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
  
  string text = value.ToString().TrimStart('-');

  count = (count % text.Length + text.Length) % text.Length;

  char[] digits = new char[text.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; ++i)
    digits[i] = text[(i + count) % digits.Length];

  string result = new string(digits);

  if (value < T.Zero)
    result = "-" + result;

  return T.Parse(result, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

The only difference between `RotateDigitsRight` and `RotateDigitsLeft` is in the `count` computation, i.e.

```
public static T RotateDigitsRight<T>(T value, int count) 
  where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {

  string text = value.ToString().TrimStart('-');

  // The only difference is here  
  count = text.Length - (count % text.Length + text.Length) % text.Length;

  char[] digits = new char[text.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; ++i)
    digits[i] = text[(i + count) % digits.Length];

  string result = new string(digits);

  if (value < T.Zero)
    result = "-" + result;

  return T.Parse(result, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DmTkp9)

Please, note that rotation as it designed can *throw exception*, e.g. if we rotate `byte` e.g. `255` by `1` will get `552` or `525` which is beyond `0..255` range.

Another problem (which I've avoided) is with negative numbers: note, that `Abs(value)` can be beyond range e.g. `Abs(int.MinValue)` can't be computed as `int`:

```
  // -1474836482
  // even if Math.Abs(int.MinValue) not a valid int
  int result = RotateDigitsLeft(int.MinValue, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning C# so I'm not sure about your `IBinaryInteger<T>`, but I'd go the way of the string:

```cs
// careful with zeroes, they may end up at the start.
static int RotateLeft(int value, int count)
{
    string sign = value < 0 ? "-" : "";
    string digits = value.ToString().TrimStart('-');
    // rotation may be > 1 full rotation,
    // let's bring it in the range < 1 full rotation
    count %= digits.Length;

    // count was a multiple of a full rotation, 
    // nothing to rotate here.
    if (count == 0)
        return value;
    
    // negative count == RotateRight
    // let's turn this into the equivalent positive value
    if (count < 0)
        count += digits.Length;
    
    return int.Parse(
        sign + 
        digits.Substring(count, digits.Length - count) + 
        digits.Substring(0, count)
    );
}

static int RotateRight(int value, int count) {
    return RotateLeft(value, -count);
}
```

Comment: Be careful with `Math.Abs(value)`: if `value == int.MinValue` you'll get an integer overflow

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math); it's really neat stuff!

Comment: If you want to support arbitrary `count` (e.g. neagtive) you can use modulo arithmetics, `count = (count % digits.Length + digits.Length) % digits.Length;`, adding `digits.Length` is not enough, e.g. for `count = -101` and `digits.Length = 5`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I cover that part in Line 3 `count %= digits.Length;` after that, `count` is in the range of `-Length < count < Length` so that adding `Length` if count is negative is sufficient. I don't know if the two modulos or the branching is worse/better, but both approaches lead eventually to the same result.