# Is there any C# bitwise shift operator that moves the overflown bits to the other tip of the variable?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-shift

Let's call it "<<<"

```
int32variable <<< numberOfBits
```

equals

```
(int32variable << numberOfBits) | (int32variable >> (32 - numberOfBits))
```

(Assuming << and >> discards overflown bits)

There is such an operator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to perform a circular bit shift in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-circular-bit-shift-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be a called a bit rotate and C# does not have such an operator.

Here's an interesting post:
[Is there a way to perform a circular bit shift in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-circular-bit-shift-in-c)

Note that your int32integer should be of type `uint` (unsigned int).

I believe bit rotate is an instructions in the Intel instruction set but as far as I know the CLR does not have bit rotate instructions.

Comment: Indeed, according to http://en.csharp-online.net/CIL_Instruction_Set while there are three bitshift instructions in the CIL, there are no rotate instructions. Which makes sense, because no (non-assembly) programming language that I'm aware of has bit rotate operators, so why should CIL support that?

Answer (score 1):

This is called a bitwise rotation.  Other languages have it, but C# does not.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812022/c-bitwise-rotate-left-and-rotate-right) for a little more detail, but the gist of it is that your current approach is about as good as you can do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no primitive operator in C# to do what you're looking for.

Ignoring the performance implications of a method call (if you're doing bitshift operations, you might care), this would be a good candidate for an extension method on Int32.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is for C#.  See this page for the list of C# operators: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(vs.71).aspx.

I think that they way you have shown in your question is probably the quickest way to do it.  I think that Java may have a shift operator like the one you are after, but not being a Java programer I can't confirm that.

Comment: I see someone else answered beat me to it.