# Shift displacement returns a wrong result

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
Console.WriteLine(7 << 4);
Console.WriteLine(7 >> (32 - 4));
```

For some reason the second method returns 0 instead of 112. But they both should be equal to one another, they both should return  112.

**UPDATE**:
It's known that `(x << n) == (x >> (32 - n))`.

Your ideas?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that those are cyclic?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377(v=vs.71).aspx for the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't *really* understand what you expect to see here:

`7 << 4` is shifting left (like multiplication) `7 * (2 ^ 4) = 7 * 16 = 112`

on another hand

`7 >> (32 - 4)` is shifting right (like division)`7/(2^28)`, that converted to integer value leads to `0`.

The question is why `Console.WriteLine` peaks integer overload: is cause you act on integer values so *expected* by `CLR` result is `int`.

So result *is* correct.

Comment: A `>>` _is not_ a division, it is a shift. Only without cycling is the result the same as from a division.

Comment: correct, I supposed that this is *not* about cycling, but looking on edited answer saw it. editing.

Comment: @AlanDert: is seems **to me** that: or it's not complete hint from the book, or there is a typo in the book, cause the *code provided* can not be correct, imo.

Answer (score 1):

```
(x << n) == (x >> (32 - n))
```

This is only true if it is a circular shift being performed, which isn't the case in C#. In C# they bits are lost if the are shifted right past the first bit.

```
//Seven = 00000111
Console.WriteLine(7 >> 1);  //00000011
Console.WriteLine(7 >> 2);  //00000001
Console.WriteLine(7 >> 3);  //00000000
Console.WriteLine(7 >> 4);  //00000000
//.
//.
//.
Console.WriteLine(7 >> 28);  //00000000
```

Explained in more detail here:
[Is there a way to perform a circular bit shift in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-circular-bit-shift-in-c)